# How do you install Eigen?

Tags: visual-studio-code, include, eigen

I'm a complete beginner at Eigen, including headers and coding in general. I tried installing Eigen's libraries to do some stuff in Visual Studio Code but I can't find the solution, or rather I don't understand what the answers mean.
I have downloaded the zip from the site but don't know what to do with it. My main question is, should you not be able to see the definition to `#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>` in vscode? Because I can't and I don't understand if I'm supposed to.

I hear many of the answers say "*Eigen c++ is a header only library: you don't have to install it, you just download it, unzip it and link your code against it.*" so does that mean i need to place the Eigen/Dense files in the default include? Because when I do I can't find them when I right click on `/Dense>` in the include code. Do I include them in my environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Download Eigen

```
$ wget -O Eigen.zip https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0.zip
```

## 2. Extract and copy to /usr/local/include

```
$ unzip Eigen.zip # it has unzipped into the library called eigen-3.4.0
```

```
$ sudo cp -r eigen-3.4.0/Eigen /usr/local/include
```

Now you can compile your source files

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory to which you copied Eigen to the include path of your project. After this `#include<Eigen/Dense>` should work.
Please google "visual C++ add directory to include path" to see how this is done.